# Abstract matrix multiplication with variables

Tags: python, numpy, symbolic-math

I know about the ability of python to do matrix multiplications.
Unfortunately I don't know how to do this abstractly? So not with 
definite numbers but with variables.

Example:

```
M = ( 1   0 ) * ( 1   d )
    ( a   c )   ( 0   1 )
```

Is there some way to define a,c and d, so that the matrix multiplication
gives me

```
( 1   d       )
( a   a*d + c )
```

?

Comment: Have a look at `sympy`, a python library for symbolic computing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) you can do this:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('a c d A B')
(a, c, d, A, B)
>>> A = Matrix([[1, 0], [a, c]])
>>> A
Matrix([
[1, 0],
[a, c]])
>>> B = Matrix([[1, d], [0, 1]])
>>> B
Matrix([
[1, d],
[0, 1]])
>>> M = A.multiply(B)
>>> M
Matrix([
[1,       d],
[a, a*d + c]])
```

Answer (score -1):

Just like any variable, an array/matrix can only be initialized with specific values. The only thing you can do is make functions to make initialization easier

```
import numpy as np

def helper(a, c, d):
    A = np.array([[1, 0], [a, c]])
    B = np.array([[1, d], [0, 1]])
    return A @ B
```

(where the `@` operator is explicit matrix multiplication operator)

Comment: Should there be a function name?

Comment: @Asterisk: yes, of course, it's a normal function. fixed the typo.